# Loop invariant for repeated calls to readLine()

Tags: java, loop-invariant

I have a while loop (shown below) that continually reads from a file until EOF is reached. I am supposed to write a loop invariant for any non-trivial loop. Is this a trivial loop? If not, what would be a loop invariant for this while loop? I have never written invariants before.

```
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Are you using some formalism like Hoare logic? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic

Answer (score -1):

You can use a fileReader:

```
while ((line = fileReader.hasNextLine()) != null) {
    String line = fileReader.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

=D